# How can I merge a web application, an admin site, and web api into one website in Azure

Tags: azure

We use Azure.

We have a web application, an admin site, and also an Web API (for mobile apps). They are all using the same database. Right now each one has its own website. But each website cost money. So how can I use just one website to have them altogether? Something like this:

```
www.myapp.com - for the web application

www.myapp.com/admin -for site admin

www.myapp.com/webapi - for web api
```

If we have our own IIS, I know we can use virtual directory. But with Azure, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx) article explained it

1. Create three projects (web, admin, and api)
2. Assign admin and api to their appropriate virtual directory
3. Publish the root project (web)
4. Set up virtual directory in azure portal
5. Publish the child projects